# Percent list slicing

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.2.3 IDLE and this is my code:

```
originalList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]

newList = orginalList[0.05:0.95] #<<<<I have no idea what I'm doing here
print (newList)
```

I have an original list of numbers, they are 1 - 100 and i want to make a new list from the original list however the new list must only have data that belongs to the sub-range 5%- 95% of the original list

so the new list must be like `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18....95]`. How do i do that? i know my newList code is wrong

Comment: If you want numbers one through 100 you should just declare it more concisely as:  
`originalList = range(1,101)`

Comment: You have `1,2,3,4` - 4 numbers excluded from the beginning and `96, 97, 98, 99, 100` - 5 numbers excluded from the end. Still, we slice off 5% both from the beginning and the end. How is your list slicing defined for percent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to slice a list into 3 parts based on percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556753/how-to-slice-a-list-into-3-parts-based-on-percentage)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
originalList.sort()
newList = originalList[int(len(originalList) * .05) : int(len(originalList) * .95)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
size = len(originalList)
newList = originalList[0.05*size - 1:0.95*size + 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sl = slice(4, 95)
print(originalList[sl])
```

Also see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice

Comment: Although the syntax `originalList[4:95]` should be preferred

Comment: and it doesn't user percents, but indexes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get part of a list, the syntax is

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
newList = [*start index*:*Index to end AT*]
```

so, the first number is the index where the sub-list **starts**, while the second number is the index at which the sublist stops (that index is **not** included).

hope this helps!

Comment: I think you need: newList = List[*start index*:*Index to end AT*]

Answer (score 0):

I'd also use a list comprehension for creating the original list... less mistake prone.

```
originalList = range(1,101)
newList = originalList[(len(originalList)*.05)-1:len(originalList)*.95]
print newList
```

Gives the desired result...

Edit: Changed range to be more concise per comment below.

Comment: `list(range(1, 101))` is more concise

Comment: Agreed, actually I don't even need more than just "originalList = range(1,101)."

Comment: But you do, because this is python 3

Comment: doesn't work for range(1, 18)

Answer (score 0):

For lists of arbitrary length, you could do:

```
>>> l = range(200)
>>> percentage = 5
>>> skip = int(len(l) * (float(percentage) / 100) / 2)
>>> len(l[skip:-skip])
190
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `fidx` module, which allows percentages as indexes:

```py
import fidx

originalList = fidx([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100])
# or better: originalList = fidx.list(range(1,101))

newList = originalList[0.05:0.95]

print (newList)
```

which returns

```py
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95]
```