# How to slice a list into 3 parts based on percentage?

Tags: python

I have a files list and I want to split it into 3 parts : training, validation and testing.
I have tries this code and I don't know if it is correct or not.

```
files = glob.glob("/dataset/%s/*" % emotion)
training = files[:int(len(files)*0.8)] #get first 80% of file list
validation = files[-int(len(files)*0.1):] #get middle 10% of file list
testing = files[-int(len(files)*0.1):] #get last 10% of file list
```

I am not sure if the testing list is duplicated or it the correct last 10% of the file list.

Comment: It is not: `len(files) == 3` leads to the indices being `(2, 0, 0)`, instead of `(2, 1, 0)` or `(2, 0, 1)`. Also, validation and testing are always equal, that is not something you want (testing should be data you have never looked at).

Comment: Adding for future readers. [Numpy split with percentage on a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788707/numpy-split-with-percentage-on-a-matrix)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can take advantage of numpy split:

```
train, validate, test = np.split(files, [int(len(files)*0.8), int(len(files)*0.9)])
```

Comment: why are you giving only 2 indices if the OP asked for 3? Also, adding a self-contained example is helpful.

Comment: @CharlieParker OP asks for 3 parts, so the values used in `np.split` (the two indices) are how it's done. Aside from that answer was accepted 3 years ago, why would you think edit will help now?

Comment: @zipa I found your very helpful answer today with google. So improving your answer even 3 years later may (potentially) help future readers.

Comment: @CharlieParker you can check the documentation for more info of how to use the syntax https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html

Answer (score 12):

Is the `testing` script a duplicate of `validation`? Yes, you create them in the exact same way, you are extracting the last 10 percent for validation and testing:

```
files = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
training = files[:int(len(files)*0.8)] #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
validation = files[-int(len(files)*0.1):] #[10]
testing = files[-int(len(files)*0.1):] #[10]
```

I suggest you do something like this if you want to stick to your original approach (however the np method is more elegant):

```
files = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
training = files[:int(len(files)*0.8)] #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
validation = files[int(len(files)*0.8):int(len(files)*0.9)] #[9]
testing = files[int(len(files)*0.9):] #[10]
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it is correct also, thank you.

Comment: I really interesting on do this but with another percents like 70%, 20% and 10%. Maybe a function that do this defining another percents. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

same as zipa's answer but with a self contained example:

```
# splitting list of files into 3 train, val, test

import numpy as np

def split_two(lst, ratio=[0.5, 0.5]):
    assert(np.sum(ratio) == 1.0)  # makes sure the splits make sense
    train_ratio = ratio[0]
    # note this function needs only the "middle" index to split, the remaining is the rest of the split
    indices_for_splittin = [int(len(lst) * train_ratio)]
    train, test = np.split(lst, indices_for_splittin)
    return train, test

def split_three(lst, ratio=[0.8, 0.1, 0.1]):
    import numpy as np

    train_r, val_r, test_r = ratio
    assert(np.sum(ratio) == 1.0)  # makes sure the splits make sense
    # note we only need to give the first 2 indices to split, the last one it returns the rest of the list or empty
    indicies_for_splitting = [int(len(lst) * train_r), int(len(lst) * (train_r+val_r))]
    train, val, test = np.split(lst, indicies_for_splitting)
    return train, val, test

files = list(range(10))
train, test = split_two(files)
print(train, test)
train, val, test = split_three(files)
print(train, val, test)
```

output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4] [5 6 7 8 9]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7] [8] [9]
```

[np.split docs.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)