# Numpy split with percentage on a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have issues to understand the following coding and I am new to python:

```
data_a, data_b, data_C = np.split(original_data.sample(frac=1, random_state=1729), 
                               [int(0.7 * len(original_data)), int(0.9*len(original_data))])
```

so my original data set has a complete of 38000 rows. After this split method the `data_a` has 26600 rows. Now `data_b` has 7600 rows, `data_c` has 3800 rows. So I do get that 70% of original_data will be 26600 rows. But why does `data_b` has 7600 rows and `data_c` 3800. I read the documentation about that split method and from what I understand the coding I would have suggested that for the rest of 30% data from my initial 38000 rows, 90% will split into `data_b` that would be 10260 rows. Not 7600 rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have do it sequentially, if you want split the remaining 30% into 90-10. Try this!

```
data_a, remaining_data = np.split(original_data.sample(frac=1, random_state=1729), 
                                   [int(0.7 * len(original_data))])
data_b, data_C = np.split(remaining_data,[int(0.9 * len(remaining_data))])

data_a.shape, data_b.shape, data_C.shape
```

output:

```
((26600,), (10260,), (1140,))
```

Comment: okay but what does my original coding do then? So it splits the original_data with 70% into data_a, and then? how do those numbers of rows come up? I want to also understand that, thanks in advance

Comment: It will slice the data into three pieces, 0 to 0.7*n , 0.7*n -0.9n,0.9n-n

Comment: Assuming n is the total number of records

Answer (score 2):

the splits percentages there are relative to the original dataset, so if you want data_b to be 90% of the 30% left after the first split you need to do something like this

```
data_a, data_b, data_C = np.split(original_data.sample(frac=1, random_state=1729), [int(0.7 * len(original_data)), int(0.97*len(original_data))])
```

that is because you specify the split points rather than the ratios of result data sets

Comment: okay but what does my original coding do then? So it splits the original_data with 70% into data_a, and then? how do those rows come up? I want to also understand that, thanks in advance

Comment: your original code splits data into 70% 20% and 10% data chunks for data_a, data_b and data_C respectfully